# How can I plot a histogram next to an image?

Tags: python, plot

I would like to evaluate an idea for finding the "right" rotation of documents. The idea is to apply an edge detector and to count the white values per row and per column. In order to evaluate it, I want to plot this count (or a histogram with a small bin size) next to the image. How can I do that?

### What I did

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import seaborn as sns

im = scipy.misc.imread("morc-0102.jpg", mode="L")
height, width = im.shape
k = np.array([[1, -1],
              [1, -1]])
im = scipy.ndimage.convolve(im, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)

# Calculate histogram
hist_height = np.zeros(height)
hist_width = np.zeros(width)
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        hist_height[y] += im[y][x]
        hist_width[x] += im[y][x]
sns.distplot(hist_height, kde=False, rug=False)
sns.distplot(hist_width, kde=False, rug=False)
sns.plt.show()
scipy.misc.imshow(im)
```

### What I want

A visualization similar to this: At the right of the image the (normalized) counts `hist_height` are plotted, at the bottom the (normalized) counts `hist_width` are plotted.

[image]

I think I have seen something very similar before. I know how to do this manually by resizing the canvas and plotting each line "by hand", but I guess libaries like matplotlib / seaborn support this directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding two bar diagrams as subplots? Like this e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# remove upper corner plot
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 2))
ax1.axis('off')

# plot some example image
imageExample = np.random.uniform(0,1,(5,5))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2.imshow(imageExample)
ax2.axis('off')

# use 'barh' for horizontal bar plot
horzSum = np.sum(imageExample,1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 2), rowspan=2, sharey=ax2)
ax3.barh(range(len(horzSum)), horzSum)
ax3.axis('off')

vertSum = np.sum(imageExample, 0)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0), colspan=2, sharex=ax2)
ax4.bar(range(len(vertSum)), vertSum)
ax4.axis('off')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: See here for the result]

Setting `width` of `bar`and `barh`to 1 and `color='r'`you get something very similar to what you aim for except for the blank spaces that you can probably get rid of somehow.

[image]